# Vim: cursor becomes invisible when viewing ALE error message

Tags: vim, terminator

I am running vim in terminal mode in Terminator on Fedora 27, and I just recently ran into the issue where whenever I put my cursor over an error from ALE in normal mode, when the error is shown in the command bar, my cursor disappears. When the message times out after waiting still for a few seconds, the cursor returns.

Note: this error exists in Fedora's 'vimx' version (With clipboard and gvim support) but NOT in the regular installation of vim, or the vimx package's gVim

I would like to have clipboard support, but this issue is impossible to work with.

Is there any fix for this issue?

My .vimrc, for reference: https://github.com/Skyb0rg007/.vimrc/

ALE: https://github.com/w0rp/ale

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9edf.jpg

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 4):

installing the lastest version of vim resolves this problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt-get update
```

see https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim